# IndexOutOfRange exception on DbDataAdapter.Fill() dataset

Tags: .net, sql, exception, ado.net, ibm-midrange

I'm running into a strange corner-case while querying an iSeries server using ADO.NET and the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries provider that comes with Client Access.

I'm running a simple query:

```
SELECT col FROM table WHERE (col LIKE 'value' OR col LIKE 'value%') FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY
```

But the adapter gives an IndexOutOfRange **ONLY** when value is, in my case, 102. Running the same query with 101 or 103 works normally. I checked the result set by running the query directly on the iSeries, it works perfectly, and the returned rows have nothing different from what I would get running the query with another value.

Pseudo-code that runs the query is as follows:

```
String query = '...' // See above query

IDbDataAdapter adapter = new iDB2DataAdapter(query, connection)
DataSet ds = new DataSet()

adapter.Fill(ds) // IndexOutOfRangeException only a certain values
```

Sample of the data that should be returned :

```
1023 29134 
1023       
1023029039
```

*Note* The blank character (and other special chars) is also found in non-failing resultsets, so I'm inclined to believe that it's not the cause of the problem.

Stack trace of the exception

```
at IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2DataReader.GetDcRow(IntPtr dataPtr, Int32 row, MpDcData[] dcData, UInt32 block)
at IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2DataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DataReaderContainer.CommonLanguageSubsetDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.LoadDataRow()
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
```

**Update** You guys were right, thanks for your help. After migrating the driver to v6r1 and installing all service packs, the problem did not go away. I ended up finding the corrupted data in my table by using the (third-party) PEEK utility, which complained about some characters being in an invalid range (less than x'40' or equal to x'FF'). The nice part about this tool is that automagically replaces invalid characters with '%', so I was able to locate the invalid data, which shows up as a blank in every other client/program (tried ODBC, STRSQL, UPDDTA).

The invalid character was actually a null char (x'00'), which the .NET driver does not seem to like.

**Last update** IBM support actually pointed me to this [APAR (SE35276)](http://www-912.ibm.com/n_dir/nas4apar.NSF/b6c9b771e38b5ea2862564c00079d110/e264e578b8595cf9862574de003c8766?OpenDocument), which solves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more I see the problem you are running into, the more I doubt the .net driver. I pull data across from a unix based system and frequently run into issues like this when the driver gets something its not expecting. My guess is that your row #102 has some data which either doesnt fit the buffer or has a data type that the driver does not expect to see at the source. Would you have some sample data? How about trying to pull 1 column at a time to see where it fails??

Comment: I'm already only pulling one column. Further tests pinpointed me to searches using '1023'. Column's datatype is char, and running manually the query returns a normal dataset (it's serial numbers for devices we sell). Ill put the data in my question.

Comment: Additionnally, I'm updating my Client Access, since we just migrated the OS to v6r1 (even though CA v5r4 is supposed to be compatible with OS v6r1) to make sure it's not a compat. issue beetwen CA and the OS

Comment: I am convinced that the data is mucked up in some way. This is usually an exception that I have come across when my source data is not good quality or someone has fat fingered something. If its a char data type, anyone could have put in blank space in that field and you wouldnt know about it. I hope I am making sense to you.

Comment: Be sure to install the latest service pack, after installing v6r1 (or any release).

Comment: @RajivVarma : I sure wish someone was fat-fingered. Unfortunately, the  data comes from barcode readers, not actual human input... Anyhow, I can't do any more tests, installing v6r1 just messed up everything, my app. won't even run anymore !

Comment: So that was it, invalid data. Would happen by any chance to know of a tool that can dump a file in its raw form ?

Comment: Just curious. How did bad data end up there? I mean the system was bar code reader entry system, right? Just curious.

Comment: Well, that I do not know. It's on old data (2 years), maybe the bar code reader was not properly configured at the time, and used null chars instead of spaces. Out of over 2 million lines of data, only 60 were bad. Anyways, if you look at my question, I updated it with a reference to the APAR that solves the problem with the .NET driver. It's just a shame that it's not mentionned anywhere in the IBM ADO.NET redbook, I had to call IBM support to get the information.

Answer (score 1):

Try using other query tools to see if you get errors there. I am with @Rajiv that there is some bad data in the table. And don't use the STRSQL command on the system that is less likely to have problems than other PC based tools. One I believe is called something like Squirrel.

Comment: So that was it, invalid data. Would happen by any chance to know of a tool that can dump a file in its raw form ?

Comment: With SQL you can view the data in hex. I don't remember the command off the top of my head, but a quick search allowed me to find it a few months back.